# Detecting low durability item minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm playing Feed The Beast Infinity Evolved, and am trying to use autonomous activators to place, and break ores using fortune III pick(s). I would like to detect when the pick is below a durability and pull it out of the activator to fix it, does anyone know of a way of doing this? I've tried AE Import busses and Fuzzy cards but there doesn't seem to be a way of setting it to pull items BELOW a durability out. I've also tried Extra Utilities Advanced Item Filters, and they don't seem to work either.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I would reccomend, although not cheap, flux pickaxes can be recharged, so fill a buffer with those that are constantly being charged and put in

Comment: You could try to make an unbreakable pick from Tconstruct,but bare in mind that you could be losing out on fortune.

Comment: Would a timer work? Do the blocks get broken at a constant rate or does it vary. Either way I think a timer would be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

To automate repair of picks there are many options.

1. Use an pick that won't be destroyed when it runs out of durability.

   Items such as Tinker's picks and fluxed pickaxes do not get destroyed when they are used up. So if you have an filter set for pulling out only empty picks, you can recharge/repair them.
2. Set specific durability

   Since item durability at most decreases by 1 per use (Assuming you are using a pick on ores), if you have something that pulls out faster than the speed your autonomous activator breaks (So the pipe will pull at least once before the item is used again), you can just set the pipe to pull out a specific durability.
3. Use AE custom fuzzy filter

   According to [this Chart](http://ae-mod.info/Fuzzy-Card/), if you put a nearly broken pick into import bus config with a fuzzy card set to 25%, it will only pull out 10% damage picks.

Answer (score 1):

On the Autonomus Activator, set one side to blue, put an Item Duct with a servo on it, set it to whitelist, put the pickaxe thats in the Autonomus activator (when its nearly broken / out of power) into the slots of the servo, and bam when the pick/hammer hits the same durability as the whitelist wanted, it'll be pulled out. Then you can pipe it over to a place to repair it, or charge it up, then send it back through another pipe into the side you're accepting ores.

Answer (score -1):

To detect low durability is when you look in your hot bar and when you mine it will show you the durability of the pickaxe. Also what I notaced was that at low durability the pickaxe becomes less efficant.

Comment: I don't think this is what the asker was asking for. - [From Review](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/165400)

Comment: About the efficiency rou are 100% wrong

Comment: please read the question before answering next time